# Why are functions masking variables after using load inside a function?

Tags: matlab, workspace, masking

Save this sample function as `test_func.m`:

```
function test_func
load test.mat
whos
alpha
```

and run this sample script:

```
alpha = 3;
save test.mat
test_func
```

Here is the output I get:

```
  Name       Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  alpha      1x1                 8  double              

??? Error using ==> alpha at 40
Not enough input arguments.

Error in ==> test_func at 4
alpha
```

---

The output of `whos` shows that the variable is loaded in the local workspace of the function. I can even put a breakpoint on line 4 of `test_func` and type `alpha` and I get the correct result, but as soon as I do a step forward with the debugger, it fails again: the function `alpha` is masking the local variable and I don't see why.

Replacing the content of `test_func` by

```
p = load('test.mat');
p.alpha
```

works fine but that's not what I'm trying to do. I would like to load variables directly inside the local workspace of the function.

To me it looks like a bug (I'm using Matlab R2011a) but if it's a *feature* can you explain it and help me find a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heh, you might be right that this is a bug. Looks really strange, because the following works

```
function test_func
load('test.mat','alpha');
whos
alpha
```

Another thing that helps is to initialize the variable before a call to load

```
function test_func
alpha = 0;
load('test.mat');
whos
alpha
```

Comment: @Simon: The above answer fixes the issue. The error stems from the fact that Matlab is an interpreted language that generously allows overloading of functions. Thus, at the onset of the function call, Matlab has to decide for each string in your function whether it is a function or a variable. Sine the interpreter has no way of knowing what `test.mat` will contain at the time it is loaded, it interprets   `alpha` as a function. Thus you should either not use function names as variable names, use `load` with an output argument (recommended), or use any of the workarounds by againor.

Comment: @Jonas thanks for explanation. I guess the same restrictions apply to eval.

Comment: @againor: indeed, that's one of the reasons eval is evil.